# Starting a gmail AppScript before selecting an email

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have a gmail AppScript (AS) for logging receipt emails. When I activate the AS with an email selected, it parses the email content pulling out pertinent data (date, merchant, amount, etc.), lets me make any edits, then lets me push the data to a Google spreadsheet. It works great in that use case, and I would like to add the option of activating the AS from the gmail UI without having an email selected to enter the data manually.

When the AS is activated without an email selected, it shows a blank form with "Get started by opening an email or conversation." This looks to be part of the framework that I probably won't be able to preempt, but I thought I'd ask; is there a way to add a button to that blank form that I could use to trigger the `getContextualAddOn(event)` function.

Comment: Maybe use a Gmail addon to save message id in properties service and then when you launch other Google Apps Script it looks for that property.